# Export results with column headers in Rapid SQL

Tags: sql, excel-2010, rapidsql

When I save the results of my query in Rapid SQL as a CSV or Excel file it doesn't include the column headers, where can I change the settings so it will include them?

Answer (score 4):

I found it:

File > Options > Results > "Include column titles when saving"